# Why is ESP32 BLE so power hungry?

Tags: rf, esp32, bluetooth-low-energy

The ESP32 consumes around 100-130mA when BLE is active and transmitting, while other BLE chips like nRF8001 only consume around 13mA when BLE is active and transmitting.

Am I missing something, or does the esp32, just consume 10x the power of other BLE chips?

ESP32 RF Consumption (page 46):
https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_datasheet_en.pdf

[image]

nRF8001 BLE Consumption (page 36):
https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/297/nRF8001_PS_v1.3-2797.pdf
[image]

Comment: Are the voltages the same?

Comment: Both is at 3.3v

Comment: You need to compare like with like. The nRF8001 is just a Bluetooth peripheral while the ESP32 is a complete microcontroller.

Comment: looks closer to double the power, not 10X.

Comment: @Finbarr the power consumption of the ESP32 without BLE is max 20mA, and the table is showing the power consumption of BLE, not including the chips other consumption

Comment: @dandavis am i bad at math or is 13 * 10 != 130?

Comment: you have to subtract the 100ma that has nothing to do with BLE, which leaves 30ma, which is about double the nRF8001's 12ma at the same -0db power.

Comment: https://lastminuteengineers.com/esp32-sleep-modes-power-consumption/, from this guide, the esp32 power consumption without any form of RF is only 3-20ma, where did you get your 100mA from?

Comment: @dandavis the highest possible power consumption of the esp32 without rf is 68ma, from the datasheet

Comment: fair nuff, I got the 100ma figure from my own observations, milage may vary, but if you're not using the ESP32 for anything else, why use an ESP32? If low power is the goal, a single-purpose chip will always be better than general-purpose chip with a wireless tack-on.

Comment: @dandavis what chip would you recommend? the project is pretty simple, i need to connect an accelerometer to a BLE module and send it to a phone, it needs to be powered from coin cell battery

Comment: im not huge into low power, but i would look into one of the ATTINY or even a 3,3v 328, both would be better than an esp32...

Comment: There’s plenty of nrf52 based modules avail and has Arduino support. As you’ve gathered the esp32 is not targeting the low power end of the market- more like wifi to BLE gateway devices. The esp32 compute performance is significantly higher than the average BLE SoC

Comment: @dandavis hm. Bluetooth is a rather complex protocol with lots of state machines. There's no such thing as a "single-purpose hardware Bluetooth transceiver"; these all are microcontrollers running a bluetooth stack. The fact that the ESP32 can *also* be used as general purpose microcontroller doesn't actually imply anything on its power efficiency.