# What is the power consumption of 200ms of Bluetooth Beacon advertising/broadcasting

Tags: power, batteries, bluetooth, esp32, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm running an ESP32 on 3 AA batteries.

It wakes up up to 1000 times a day, then sends a Beacon advertisting for 200 milliseconds, and then goes to deep sleep, until `GPIO0` and `GND` are connected (then it wakes up again, etc.).

**What is the power consumption? How long can I expect it to run?**

I have read [Why is ESP32 BLE so power hungry?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/615765/why-is-esp32-ble-so-power-hungry) but I don't know exactly which mode it is, which consumption it is.

I have also read [BLE taking too much power](https://github.com/espressif/esp-idf/issues/947#issuecomment-500312453).

I'm guessing : 1 month = 31 days * 1000 times a day * 0.2 seconds * 100 mA = 172 mAh, is that roughly correct ?
I'm only looking for an order of magnitude, not a real measurement (this would depend on battery brand, etc.) : days, weeks, months, 1 year of runtime?

Here is the code:

```
#include "BLEDevice.h"
#include "BLEUtils.h"
#include "BLEBeacon.h"
#include "esp_sleep.h"
RTC_DATA_ATTR int bootcount = 0;
BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising;
void setup() {
    bootcount++;  
    pinMode(0, INPUT_PULLUP);
    esp_sleep_enable_ext0_wakeup(GPIO_NUM_0, 0);
    BLEDevice::init("");
    pAdvertising = BLEDevice::getAdvertising();
    BLEBeacon oBeacon = BLEBeacon();
    oBeacon.setManufacturerId(0x4C00);
    oBeacon.setProximityUUID(BLEUUID("12345678-5558-444a-9999-777777777777"));
    oBeacon.setMajor((bootcount & 0xFFFF0000) >> 16);
    oBeacon.setMinor(bootcount&0xFFFF);
    BLEAdvertisementData oAdvertisementData = BLEAdvertisementData();
    BLEAdvertisementData oScanResponseData = BLEAdvertisementData();
    oAdvertisementData.setFlags(0x04);
    std::string strServiceData = "";
    strServiceData += (char) 26;
    strServiceData += (char) 0xFF;
    strServiceData += oBeacon.getData(); 
    oAdvertisementData.addData(strServiceData);
    pAdvertising->setAdvertisementData(oAdvertisementData);
    pAdvertising->setScanResponseData(oScanResponseData);
    pAdvertising->setAdvertisementType(ADV_TYPE_NONCONN_IND);
    pAdvertising->start();
    delay(200);
    pAdvertising->stop();
    esp_deep_sleep_start();
}
void loop() {
}
```

Comment: I would measure current consumption over an hour, then calculate from there.

Comment: @Lundin It's not easy in my current setup, sometimes there can be 100 triggers in one hour, sometimes 0, etc. Also I don't have an accurate current consumption meter for these batteries (I only have this ESP32, computer, multimeter (not so precise), but no other electronic stuff).

Comment: @Lundin Also, do you see ways to lower the power consumption in my current code here?

Comment: I don't know these libs. Does `delay` actually put the MCU in sleep mode or does it just hog 100% CPU?

Comment: Good question @Lundin, I don't know. Maybe we cannot go in sleep mode while it's advertising. (I adapted this sample code from an ArduinoBLE library code example)

Comment: I mean MCU sleep mode, not BLE sleep mode. The BLE will have to be active. I think in the general use-case you want to pair it with something asap and then never do things like advertising again.